# How to read atom feed in .NET

Tags: .net, atom-feed

I write code given below to read Atom feed.

```
string strUrL = "http://loluyede.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
        WebRequest objWR = WebRequest.Create(strUrL);
        WebProxy objWP = new WebProxy("strAddress", 1978);
        objWP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        objWR.Proxy = objWP;
        StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(objWR.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        AtomFeed feed = AtomFeed.Load(objSR);
```

at the end of the statement following error comes

```
ERROR In Code:
The type initializer for 'Atom.Utils.DefaultValues' threw an exception.
```

ERROR on Page

```
Server Error in '/WebAppUI' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream
```

Anybody suggest me what i have to do.

Comment: Are you using a library for this, e.g. http://atomnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes! you are right.I am using Atom.NET.dll

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The solution is much simpler:

```
string strUrl = "http://loluyede.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
Stream responseStream = WebRequest.Create(strUrl).GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string strTheWholeFeedAsString = objSR.ReadToEnd();
```

To get it fully up and running you should change from AtomFeed to [ASP.Net RSS Toolkit](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/) (free from codeplex).

Good luck!

---

EDITED on 2010-09-12:

Given the fact, that the AtomFeed project is discontinued and written for .NET v1.1 therefore too old, I've created a sample application fetching your feed using RSS Toolkit. Feel free to download the source codes from **http://www.isource.ro/StackOverflow/RssReaderTest.zip**.

If you have questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Bad! You're just retrieving the text as string, **NOT** parsing the document into an object you can browse!!!

Comment: To get it fully up and running you should change from AtomFeed to ASP.Net RSS Toolkit (free from codeplex). See link above. Have fun!

Comment: Hi,I tried AtomFeed to ASP.Net RSS but not got any conclusion.How can i resolve "The type initializer for 'Atom.Utils.DefaultValues' threw an exception." ERROR that comes on "AtomFeed feed = AtomFeed.Load(objSR);" line of code.

Comment: I also tried AtomFeed feed = AtomFeed.LoadXml(strTheWholeFeedAsString);but same execption is coming.

Answer (score 2):

Have  a look at thesyndication-namespace in [System.ServiceModel.Syndicationfeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using [Atom.NET](http://atomnet.sourceforge.net/). That's 5 years old and supplied (as far as I can see) as a .NET 1.x assembly. That appears to be the problem - if you rebuild the bundled source in VS2005 or later then you'll get an assembly you can use.

Unfortunately I don't know the technical reason why the bundled binary doesn't work sorry.